# SlidingMenu shows blsck when used with Map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, slidingmenu

I have developed an application. In it, I have used a `fragment` for showing `Map`. The layout only has a top `title bar` and a `fragment`. In the `sliding menu` `layout` I have `title bar` and some `buttons`. `On click` of a `button` in main `layout` I show the `menu`.

The problem is that the `menu` is not showing up. Instead of `menu` there is only black color, But I am getting the `title bar` of `menu`. So i think the problem is the due to the `map` because the height of the black zone is same as that of the `map`

I am using [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) for showing sliding menu.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639

There are workarounds in comments. Maybe something will work out for you.